# While Loop is Infinite

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm working on a code to calculate taxes. I want this while segment to make sure the user inputs a valid positive integer. It works unless a string is entered, and it then enters an infinite loop. How do I make it repeat the loop and let the user enter another input, rather than an infinite loop?

```
    int dependentsRerun = 0;//makes user enter valid input for dependents
    while(dependentsRerun == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number of dependents: ");
        if(stdin.hasNextInt()) {
            int dependents = stdin.nextInt();
            if(dependents>=0) {
                dependentsRerun = 1;
            }//end if dependents>=0
            else {System.out.println("Invalid input");}//dependents negative
        }//end if hasNextInt
        else {System.out.println("Invalid input");}//dependents not an integer
    }//end while dependentsRerun
```

Comment: Please tag a language, e.g. c# or Java.

Comment: `if(dependents>=0)` is never true.

Comment: When the next input isn't an `int` you enter an infinite loop. Add an `stdin.next()` to consume the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your code in a try block then catch the InputMismatchException and then catch the input line so it clears the buffer.

```
    int dependentsRerun = 0;//makes user enter valid input for dependents
    while(dependentsRerun == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number of dependents: ");
        try{
                int dependents = stdin.nextInt();
                if(dependents>=0) {
                    dependentsRerun = 1;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                }
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                //catches input and clears
                stdin.nextLine();
           }
        }

}
```

Edit:

This is probably a better way to structure the loop

```
     while(true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter number of dependents: ");
        try{
                int dependents = stdin.nextInt();
                if(dependents >= 0) {
                    //stops loop and moves on
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Can't enter a negative number.");
                }
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                //catches input and clears
                stdin.nextLine();
           }
        }
}
```